# How to handle Ajax request to change huge content

Tags: javascript, ajax

Before I go on, I would like to say, that I know how to use AJAX to send and receive messages (texts), and that sort, but what I don't understand is that, if we are using AJAX to change a content of a site with images, divs and other elements combined [like this example here](http://m.pathe.ch/#/lausanne/programm_heute.php) where if you click on the movie row, the content changes. I have mostly just been replacing texts, fetching something from db, and inserting it to div. But this is different, it is just more than content, so my question is how is this done? I am wandering if I should just do:

```
   ...
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){ 
          doc.querySelector('.movie-detail').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
        }
   ...
```

Where `xmlhttp.responseText` would be something like this:

```
<div class="row-a">
    <img src="img/foo.png" alt="..." />
    <p class="text"> some title </p>
    <p class="text"> some content </p>
</div>
```

This seems unconventional to me, as I am containing the entire above HTML code inside the responseText. The alternative way would be to create element for each div, image, paragraph and nest them which would take lots and lots of codes and effort.

So, at the end, I just want to know if I am missing something, or if the solution is from those that I mentioned.

Comment: My suggest would make your data in json and populate the DOM in jquery. coz I believe you might encounter some string problems. (happened to me before) and for result you would like to paginate them. control the numbers of result rather than getting it all

Comment: So, it's always jQuery to the rescue :) I was hoping there was another way around to this. Thanks for the json hint I was going to return the data in php array format, but json is much better. Any reference to any of this?

Comment: for what you're doing i'd suggest angular.js to the rescue rather than jQuery :)

Comment: If all you want is the HTML content, then returning a string of HTML is a perfectly fine way to go.  No need to go JSON and just make a lot more code for yourself to turn the JSON into HTML if all you ever need is the HTML.

Comment: jfriend00 No. It has images too, and maybe forms as well, so embedding everything in the responseText seems bad practice in this case. I will give angular a go as @andrew suggested.